# How to change protection level of menustrip so I can code in other form where menustrip isn't it

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, menustrip

EDIT: **If I change in Home Form private to public void then I must do a kinda concvert to bool from void... but I don't know how that works. Can you help me guys?**

I am stuck here in the code.... I wanted to know how to access to my other form which has menustrip from another form.

E.G:

I want that clicking on the menustrip from other form where menustrip doesn't exists.

Here is the code:

Form 1

```
Home frm = new Home();
frm.IsMdiContainer = true;
if(frm.Controls["todasEntradasToolStripMenuItem"].Click += frm.todasEntradasToolStripMenuItem_Click)
       {
            {something}
       }
```

The form Home is "frm" variable and it is where it has the menu strip. I want help to change the protection level so that this form (Form1) can accept this code... Anyone can help me please?

Comment: Winforms has built-in support for merging the menu of a child window with the menu of the MDI container.  Not using this feature is a mistake.  Otherwise simple to do, change the *Modifiers* property in the Properties Window from Private to Public.

Comment: Do you know that the form where you want to do something is mdi child of your home form. If that is the case then its possible and i can guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution 1 (nice):
Add your Click event in some Init-method or the constructor in Home. There you can access your control.

```
todasEntradasToolStripMenuItem.Click += todasEntradasToolStripMenuItem_Click;
```

Also in Home you define a new event:

```
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> TodasEntradasToolStripMenuItemClick;

    private void OnTodasEntradasToolStripMenuItemClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (todasEntradasToolStripMenuItem != null)
        {
            TodasEntradasToolStripMenuItemClick(this, e);
        }
    }
```

In the Click handler you raise your own public event:

```
    private void todasEntradasToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        OnTodasEntradasToolStripMenuItemClick(e);
    }
```

In Form1 you add your Handler to this public event:

```
        Home frm = new Home();
        frm.TodasEntradasToolStripMenuItemClick += frm_TodasEntradasToolStripMenuItemClick;
```

In this handler you can "do something":

```
    private void frm_TodasEntradasToolStripMenuItemClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do something
    }
```

Solution 2 (do not do it):
You asked for changing the protection level. So you can change

```
private todasEntradasToolStripMenuItem
```

in Home to

```
internal todasEntradasToolStripMenuItem
```

or even

```
public todasEntradasToolStripMenuItem
```

But I do not suggest you not to do this. You should choose Solution 1. With Solution 2 you would open Home for more changes than you have to.

Comment: I still don't get how do I add the Handler in Form1 to public?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for my short answer at first. I edited it now and added much more details.

Comment: Well, I did just paste the code that i used in Form1 menustripclick and put it inside of the home menustripclick and it is working now.